# how to replace a search with multiple lines in emacs?

Tags: emacs

how to replace a match with multiple lines in emacs.

Example:- replacing "Dog" with
 barking
 animal

as shown below

```
The Dog
```

with

```
The Barking
animal
```

I tried \n in the command replace-regexp, for which emacs throws error saying 
    Invalid use of `\' in replacement text

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As documented [in this article](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/008872.html), the answer is to use <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd> to enter your newline if you're using <kbd>M-x</kbd> `replace-string`

So for you:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `replace-string` <kbd>RET</kbd>
`Dog` <kbd>RET</kbd> `Barking` <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd> `animal` <kbd>RET</kbd>